# Concurrent reads and updates

Tags: sql-server, concurrency, isolation-level

Let's say I have a table with 50,000 transactions that need to be processed in the background in the same order they were received. I have a Windows service that polls for transactions, picks them up, updates the transaction table that that record is picked by this instance at a particular time. All this works perfectly well.

Now, suppose I want to scale out the processing and run another instance of the same service on another machine, how do I ensure that both instances do not pick up the same records?

I  either have both instances picking the same record and one instance overwriting update of the other or if I have additional filters in the update query to prevent that I have one instance picking up some records and updating it and the other instance running but not able to do anything simply because the record is already updated.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: How are you currently marking a row as processed?

Comment: There are additional columns in my transactional table that I update. Specifically I am updating which server instance picked the request and at what time it picked.

Comment: You should put that in the question

Comment: I have "...updates the transaction table that that record is picked by this instance at a particular time. ....."

Answer (score 2):

My favourite way of achieving this is the `OUTPUT` clause. 
Here is an example:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- example setup for the queue table
DECLARE @queue TABLE (
    transaction_id int PRIMARY KEY,
    processed bit
);


-- some sample data
INSERT INTO @queue 
VALUES
    (1,0),
    (2,0),
    (3,0),
    (4,0),
    (5,0);
```

Now the processing thread:

```
-- processing thread
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @transaction_id int;

    DECLARE @row_to_process TABLE (
        transaction_id int
    );

    BEGIN TRAN;

    BEGIN TRY

        DELETE FROM @row_to_process;

        UPDATE Q
        SET processed = 1
        OUTPUT inserted.transaction_id 
            INTO @row_to_process
        FROM (
            SELECT TOP(1) transaction_id, processed
            FROM @queue
            WHERE processed = 0
            ORDER BY transaction_id
        ) AS Q;

        IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        BEGIN
            COMMIT;
            -- sleep for 5 seconds then restart the loop
            WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'; 
            CONTINUE;
        END

        SELECT @transaction_id = transaction_id
        FROM @row_to_process;

        IF @transaction_id IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR(N'processing transaction N. %d.',1,1, @transaction_id) WITH NOWAIT;
            EXEC whatever_processes_the_row @transaction_id;
        END

        COMMIT;

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK;
        THROW;
    END CATCH
END
```

If you're marking the row as processed by deleting it, it works in the same way: the only thing you have to do is change the `UPDATE` statement into a `DELETE` statement and pull the current `@transaction_id` from the `DELETED` logical table.

Comment: Thank you.  That helps. I am however a bit concerned about the "while 1=1" loop - possibilities of becoming infinite and the need to build a break condition.

Comment: Obviously that's a simplification.